# Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin doesn't support for firefox 23.0. How can I solve this issue?

Tags: google-app-engine, firefox, gwt, web-applications

While running a web application project using google app engine, I came to know that GWT developer plugin supports only for firefox 3.0 to 22.0 versions. I have firefox 23.0 installed on my system and I don't want to revert back to 22.0 version. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 23 is still in beta, so you're unlikely to see an official GWT plugin release for that. You can try forcing the plug anyway, it will most likely work fine.